# Create map with kendo ui

Tags: d3.js, kendo-ui, geojson

I exported such polygons to a geojson format from [overpass-turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1f8Q). I can display this data with [d3js](https://jsfiddle.net/6szLc90w/) by passing the geojson from a local source.

I want to know how to setup this [map in kendo-ui](https://jsfiddle.net/nruh7adw/)? For instance my geojson object is stored in the variable `map`, then assigning `map` to attribute `dataSource` does not work.  For a working example please see the links to jsfiddle. It needs some time till the content is loaded.

```
$("#svganchor").kendoMap({
    center: [13.53, 52.41],
    zoom: 5,
    layers: [{
        type: "shape",
        dataSource: map,
        style: {
            fill: {
                color: "blue",
                opacity: 0.7
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load the data from local, then you have to simulate the transport function.

```
          dataSource: {
                type: "geojson",
                transport: {
                    read: function(e) {
                            e.success(map);
                    }
                }
            }
```